# Css opacity attribute

Tags: html, css, opacity

I have one question. Here is example:

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

ul {
  background: green;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Link1</li>
    <li>Link2</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<header>
  <h1>123</h1>
</header>
```

And problem is that, `ul` is also have `opacity`. By all this I mean that `nav` tag is okay, it has opacity of 0.8, but my `ul` tag shoud not have opacity, and it doesn't if you look in css in browser, but I still can see `h1` text behind the `ul` and `li` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  //background: #000;
  //opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

ul {
  background: green;
  //opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Link1</li>
    <li>Link2</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<header>
  <h1>123</h1>
</header>
```

How about using `rgba()`?

Comment: Thanks, It worked!

Comment: @Genjik I think you forgot to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`rgba()`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_colors.asp), where the 4th parameter takes `0.0` for fully transparent up to 1.0 for fully opaque while the first three parameter takes the `red`, `blue`, `green` value of the color you want to use.

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

ul {
  background: green;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Link1</li>
    <li>Link2</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<header>
  <h1>123</h1>
</header>
```